# CKEditor, JQuery: Animation breaks the editor

Tags: jquery, animation, ckeditor

I initialize a CKEditor in a `<div style="display:none" id="container"></div>` element.

`$('#container').show();` shows the editor and everything works.

However, if i combine the call with an animation like `$('#container').show('blind');`, the editor comes to the foreground (btw: the animation looks sweet), but however, the editor gets broken.

Did someone had the same problem? Is this a jquery or a CKEditor bug?
I think its a scaling problem, because scale and blind don't work.

Comment: I'd use Firebug to check the CSS info for the container, both in the case where it does work, and in the case where it doesn't. If there's a difference, that could be the problem.

Comment: There isn't any difference after the effect.

Comment: @AkaBkn did you found any solution of this? I'm having this issue too. This killing me.. didn't find any solution. 

Please share if you have found any solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. As a work around I used the `.slideDown()` function from plain jQuery and the CKEditor worked. Something like this:

```
$('#container').slideDown();
```

As well as `.slideDown()` there is also `.slideUp()` and `.slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered a work-around for this. If you re-paste your data once again after the animation, it seems to work! For example:

```
$j(".content-other").hide('slide', {direction: "right"}, 400, function () {
        $j(this).html(data); // show it initially for the slide-in
        $j(this).show('slide', {direction: "right"}, 400, function () {
            $j(this).html(data); // after the animation's done, place it again
        });
});
```

The second html() is what's important. Seems the animating process does something to it.